# How can I capture the video mirrored on android

Tags: video, camera

I want to make an app which records video upside down - flipped not rotated 180.

I made a success with preview - matrix applied textureview.

But how can I record the video flipped?

The SDK is api-16.

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    mCamera = CameraHelper.getDefaultCameraInstance();


    // We need to make sure that our preview and recording video size are supported by the
    // camera. Query camera to find all the sizes and choose the optimal size given the
    // dimensions of our preview surface.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size optimalSize = CameraHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes,
            mPreview.getWidth(), mPreview.getHeight());

    // Use the same size for recording profile.
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    profile.videoFrameWidth = optimalSize.width;
    profile.videoFrameHeight = optimalSize.height;


    Log.d("Tag", profile.videoFrameHeight + " : " + profile.videoFrameWidth);
    // likewise for the camera object itself.

    parameters.setPreviewSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    try {
        // Requires API level 11+, For backward compatibility use {@link setPreviewDisplay}
        // with {@link SurfaceView}

        Matrix mx = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0,0, mPreview.getWidth(), 960);
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();

        mx.postRotate(90, centerX, centerY);

        mx.postScale(1f, -1.5f);
        mx.postTranslate(0, 960);

        mPreview.setTransform(mx);

        mPreview.requestLayout();
        mPreview.invalidate();



        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mPreview.getSurfaceTexture());



    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Surface texture is unavailable or unsuitable" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }


    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();


    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);



    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT );
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(180);
    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher).

    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);

    // Step 4: Set output file
    //mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(
    //        CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("mnt/extSdCard/11.mp4");

    // Step 5: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```